# handling file descriptors java

Tags: java, file-descriptor

whenever our application handles a large amount of http request, the error "too many open files" is being displayed on the logs and I am sure that error is connected to the socket and creates a new file descriptor instance see the error below:

```
[java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:447), java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:510), 
java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1101), 
org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:122), 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnecti
onOperator.java:148), 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149), 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121), 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561), org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415),
```

when I saw on the internet that I should use

```
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

the errors were reduced but not that many, I have a feeling that my consuming of resources is not that enough to clear all of the file descriptors. Right I am looking for different answers asides on changing the ulimit because the application will be deployed on other server that we can't configure if changes are needed.

Comment: Well this one is tricky, what OS are you using?

Comment: we are using linux right now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Linux, there are some configurations which might be changed to solve the problem. First of all, what is happening? After you close the socket in Java, the operating systems sets it to `TIME_WAIT` state and that is because something still might be sent to the socket, so OS maintains it open for some time to make sure all the packets will be received (basically the packets which are still on the way and you need some kind of response for those must be received).

As far as I know it's not an optimal solution for this problem, but it works. You should set `tcp_tw_recycle` and `tcp_tw_reuse` to 1, to allow fast re-usage of sockets by OS. Now how it is done, depends on the Linux version you have. For instance in Fedora I could do something like:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
```

to set those temporarily (untill reboot). It is up to you to find out how to set those permanently, cuz I'm not very strong at Linux Administration.

**EDIT: I'm mentioning once again, it is not an optimal solution, try to think what can be changed in application before messing with OS configuration.**

Comment: thanks for your explanation :) so meaning the way i close and use entities on the code is enough and what i should do next is to confugure the operating sysyem? well i guess i have to find a way on how to do that on ubuntu ( for development) and red hat (server)

Comment: `netstat -nat` will show you open sockets and their status.. And once again the solution I provide you is not optimal, try to explore alternatives (maybe connection pooling inside your application?), because there is a possibility of receiving late packet on newly created connection, which might cause some strange behavior..

Comment: thanks again :) i am thinking of thr connection pooling a while ago but my question is, will that connection pooling will cause for the application to respond slower? because what if the connection pooling only accepts 100 request at a time and there are 400 more waiting then they have to wait a little longer as long as the first 100 is not yet finished, right? please correct if i ak wrong :)

Comment: There is no concrete response to your question without careful analysis of the software you are working on. If you make a request that takes long time to complete, obviously at some point you will run out of connections available in the pool and waiting time will increase (potential bottleneck), but at this point you could increase the number of server instances and put a load balancer, which would direct the requests to different machines for example.